# ArrayOfNulls with LiveData in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a custom class Card. I use it to create an array using `arrayOfNulls()` like this:

```
var cards: Array<Array<Card?>?> = Array(n) { arrayOfNulls<Card?>(n) }
```

where n is an `Int(Kotlin)`.

Now I need to move this variable in my `ViewModel` class and wrap it around a `LiveData` class (preferably MutableLiveData).

How should I declare & initialize the cards variable in my `AndroidViewModel` class?

Answer (score 0):

Create a MutableLiveData-variable, that wraps your cards and add it as class variable inside your ViewModel:

`val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Array<Array<Card?>?>>()`

You can now access and subscribe to this variable from your Fragment/Activity/...

To change the value of the mutableLiveData-Variable just change the value:

`mutableLiveData .value = cards`

and all subscribers of this LiveData-Variable will get the new value.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. I also want to initialize each Card item with null and that's why I was using arrayOfNulls() method. Do you know how to do that in a fast way?